# Multiple Python installs; import scipy is failing with WinError 193

Tags: python, scipy

I install the package  by using anaconda. But when I import in Jupyter Notebook it failed with `OSError: WinError 193`
Below is the Error message:

```
<ipython-input-1-4363d2be0702> in <module>
----> 1 import scipy

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py in <module>
    104 
    105 # Allow distributors to run custom init code
--> 106 from . import _distributor_init
    107 
    108 __all__ += _num.__all__

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\scipy\_distributor_init.py in <module>
     24     if os.path.isdir(libs_path):
     25         for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(libs_path, '*dll')):
---> 26             WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))

~\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    371 
    372         if handle is None:
--> 373             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    374         else:
    375             self._handle = handle
```

Here are what I think might be the reasons it doesn't work:

1. I have multiple versions: Python 3.7 and 3.8. I downloaded them from download, and I delete Python 3.7 using the **control panel**. However, after I delete them, I can still find some files of Python 3.7. I don't know why. How can I completely delete Python 3.7 by hand because I think that could be an issue for this.
2. The environment might be a mess. But I don't know how to check whether it is correct or not.

I also go to command prompt enter **pip list** to check what package I have downloaded so far. I can find **scipy** in the list. Below are the results.

```
Package            Version
------------------ -------
attrs              19.3.0
backcall           0.2.0
bleach             3.1.5
colorama           0.4.3
decorator          4.4.2
defusedxml         0.6.0
entrypoints        0.3
ipykernel          5.3.0
ipython            7.15.0
ipython-genutils   0.2.0
ipywidgets         7.5.1
jedi               0.17.0
Jinja2             2.11.2
jsonschema         3.2.0
jupyter            1.0.0
jupyter-client     6.1.3
jupyter-console    6.1.0
jupyter-core       4.6.3
jupyterthemes      0.20.0
lesscpy            0.14.0
MarkupSafe         1.1.1
mistune            0.8.4
mpmath             1.1.0
nbconvert          5.6.1
nbformat           5.0.6
nose               1.3.7
notebook           6.0.3
numpy              1.18.5
packaging          20.4
pandas             1.0.4
pandocfilters      1.4.2
parso              0.7.0
pickleshare        0.7.5
pip                20.1.1
ply                3.11
prometheus-client  0.8.0
prompt-toolkit     3.0.5
Pygments           2.6.1
pyparsing          2.4.7
pyrsistent         0.16.0
python-dateutil    2.8.1
pytz               2020.1
pywin32            227
pywinpty           0.5.7
pyzmq              19.0.1
qtconsole          4.7.4
QtPy               1.9.0
scipy              1.4.1
Send2Trash         1.5.0
setuptools         47.1.0
six                1.15.0
sympy              1.6
terminado          0.8.3
testpath           0.4.4
tornado            6.0.4
traitlets          4.3.3
wcwidth            0.2.4
webencodings       0.5.1
widgetsnbextension 3.5.1
```

Comment: Please edit your question to post that actual OSError (as text, not image) into the question. And a translation from Chinese to English. Otherwise we can't diagnose it. See also all the existing posts on `import`, was your PYTHONPATH set, are you sure the package is in fact correctly installed, how was the package installed (pip/conda/other). Was the package installed as administrator or user, and you're running as the other? etc.

Comment: jupyter has almost nothing to do with this one.

Comment: **How are you installing Python?** from download? Anaconda/conda? When you say you deleted (not uninstalled) 3.7, how exactly did you do that? Is there still a dangling 3.7 site-packages directory, for example? Best to make sure you clean-uninstall 3.7 (and possibly 3.8) before doing anything else.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the help on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please add all the missing relevant details that we'd need to diagnose this.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion.  I edited and added some stuff.

Comment: I already gave you suggestions that will often solve this. Did you try them? *When you say you deleted (not uninstalled) 3.7, how exactly did you do that? Is there still a dangling 3.7 site-packages directory, for example? Best to make sure you clean-uninstall 3.7 (and possibly 3.8) before doing anything else.* "*I deleted Python 3.7 using the (Windows?) control panel"* doesn't make any sense. Forget the GUI, go manually check the 3.7 install directories and verify it's been fully and cleanly uninstalled. If it hasn't, fix it.